# How to get nested sftp within ssh script to wait for password prompt

Tags: bash, unix, ssh, pipe, sftp

What I am trying to accomplish here is the following. I want to ssh into a server, from within that server, sftp into another server, retrieve a file, store it and then retrieve some information from it and store it in the `file` variable. The problem being, that client@server.com requires a password and when the sftp command is in the ssh script, it doesn't wait to ask for the user to input the password. How can I get the script to wait for the user to enter a password before proceeding with the rest of the script.

```
KEYPAIR="..."
PUBLIC_DNS="..."
ssh -i $KEYPAIR "ec2-user@$(sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' <<<"$PUBLIC_DNS")" << EOF

    echo "Finding latest file"
    echo ls -t | sftp client@server.com > files.txt
    file=$(head -n 2 files.txt | sed -n '2p')

EOF
```

Comment: If its OK to use ssh instead of sftp you can use ssh -t for jump between two servers.  ssh user1@server1 -t user2@server2 ls -t > files.txt

Comment: I think it needs to be sftp, because I can't manage to ssh into the second server

Answer (score 1):

What about option to sftp password authentication: install from first server the ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys at anotherServer. Then your sftp session on anotherServer will start authenticated. Therefor the script on the first server then can derive the needed information and there no more need to type password.

Comment: I'd rather not store the password anywhere. I'd like the user to have to input it every time the script runs

Comment: What do you mean with 'I'd rather not store the password anywhere.' You don't store the password at all. You  copying id_rsa.pub content elsewhere, in your case to 'anotherComputer'.  You are authorizing your instance as id@computer to run that service from anotherComputer. To disclose  id_rsa.pub content  to anybody doesn't  compromise the security. In opposite way, eliminating the use of password while using id_rsa.pub increases the  security.